# Timegaps delete all backup file

Tags: backup

i've read about timegaps on this forum and i'm going to try it,but when i give this command: timegaps -d months12 *.zip timegaps delete all the file in the path i've created for test,but it could save at least 1 file right?
Maybe i do something wrong, but don't understand what, can someone help me?

Comment: Where is this mysterious `timegaps` command you speak of? I've never heard of it. What type of system are you trying to run this on?

Comment: the command is that: timegaps -d months12 *. file exection    It will keep just 1 file, but it delete all, i'm trying on last version of debian

Comment: I understand that. What type of system are you running this on?

Comment: i'm trying on the last version of debian

Answer (score 0):

Timegaps seems to be a somewhat [obscure script released in 2014](https://gehrcke.de/timegaps/) and not updated since then. Since it's not a standard *nix tool, it's highly unlikely that you'll find anyone here that can help you out.

The best I can recommend is that you check out the documentation for the tool, or contact the author and try to work it out.

Comment: thx ill' try that way or maybe is better  creare a script  for delete old file of backup.

Comment: If all you're trying to do is delete old backup files, that can be accomplished *much* more easily with trusted, built-in tools you already have on your server.

Comment: i wanna delete all old backup except 1 for each month, and timegaps seems a good way